# How to change links in jsp to buttons

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I faced with the following problem:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lab2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
    <form>
        Period: <input type="number" name="period" size="50"> <br>
        Faculty: <input type="text" name="faculty" size="50"> <br>
        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/calculatePaymentForSeveralSemesters?value=<%=request.getParameter("period")%>&faculty=<%=request.getParameter("faculty")%>">Calculate payment for several semesters</a> 
        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/showTwoSmallestFaculties">Show two smallest faculties</a> 
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I have to enter data to the inputs, then click on Submit and only then I can click on the link. But is there any way to navigate to another pages by clicking on the button and passing parameters to other pages? I will appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: can you use `js` or `jquery` for this ?

Answer (score 0):

> But is there any way to navigate to another pages by clicking on the
>   button and passing parameters to other pages?

Yeah. You can just pass the values as inputs within a form:

```
   <form method="get" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/calculatePaymentForSeveralSemesters">
        Period: <input type="number" name="period" value="${period}" size="50"> <br>
        Faculty: <input type="text" name="faculty" value="${faculty} size="50"> <br>
        <button type="submit">Calculate payment for several semesters</button> 
    </form>


   <form method="get"  action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/showTwoSmallestFaculties">
        Period: <input type="number" name="period" value="${period}" size="50"> <br>
        Faculty: <input type="text" name="faculty" value="${faculty} size="50"> <br>
        <button type="submit">Show two smallest faculties</button> 
    </form>
```

You could also just do it with javascript...

```
    Period: <input id="period" type="number" name="period" value="${period}" size="50"> <br>
    Faculty: <input id="faculty" type="text" name="faculty" value="${faculty} size="50"> <br>
   <button type="submit" onclick="showFaculties">Show two smallest faculties</button> 
   <button type="submit" onclick="calculatepayments">Calculate payment for several semesters</button> 

<script>

var period = document.getElementById("period").value;
var faculty = document.getElementById("faculty").value;

function showFaculties(){
     window.location = "/calculatePaymentForSeveralSemesters?value="+period+"&faculty="+faculty;
}
function calculatepayments(){
     window.location = "/showTwoSmallestFaculties"
}

<script>
```

Also, scriptlets are highly discouraged against... you don't need to do this:

```
<%=request.getParameter("period")%>
```

just this is fine:

```
${period}
```

Why scriptlets are discouraged:

[How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)